# Filtrar arquivos da mesma data ? JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

*Olá, Tenho um array com vários objetos gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar os objetos que tenha date igual a "02" por exemplo:*

```
 let arr = [
  { name: "file0.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file1.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file2.xml", date: "03", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file3.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file4.xml", date: "03", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file5.xml", date: "02", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file6.xml", date: "04", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file7.xml", date: "04", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file8.xml", date: "05", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file9.xml", date: "02", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file10.xml", date: "06", size: "0" }
];

console.log('\n\n---> Meus Dados da Base \n\n')
console.log(arr)
console.log('\n\n Fim <---\n\n')

let obj = arr.find(o => o.date ==='02');
console.log(obj)
```

**Assim exibir ::**

```
[ { name: 'file0.xml', date: '02', size: '10823' },
  { name: 'file1.xml', date: '02', size: '10823' },
  { name: 'file3.xml', date: '02', size: '10823' },
  { name: 'file5.xml', date: '02', size: '09504' },
  { name: 'file9.xml', date: '02', size: '13628' }
]
```

Comment: Ao invés de `arr.find(o => o.date ==='02')`, que só irá encontrar a primeira ocorrência, utilize `arr.filter(o => o.date ==='02')` para encontrar todas as ocorrências.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) irá procurar um item do array que satisfaça a condição que você colocar dentro do *callback*, retornando o primeiro elemento que a satisfizer.

Para retornar um novo *array* com todos os elementos que satisfaçam a condição, você deve utilizar o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), conforme também foi indicado nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/455279/filtrar-arquivos-da-mesma-data-js#comment868482_455279).

Assim:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "file0.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file1.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file2.xml", date: "03", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file3.xml", date: "02", size: "10823" },
  { name: "file4.xml", date: "03", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file5.xml", date: "02", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file6.xml", date: "04", size: "09504" },
  { name: "file7.xml", date: "04", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file8.xml", date: "05", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file9.xml", date: "02", size: "13628" },
  { name: "file10.xml", date: "06", size: "0" }
];

const filtered = arr.filter(o => o.date ==='02');

console.log(filtered)
```